# Having trouble starting node socket server on amazon ec2, issue with port permissions

Tags: node.js, sockets, amazon-ec2, server, port

My server code looks like this:

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
var server = app.listen(80, '0.0.0.0');

app.use(express.static('public'));

console.log("My socket server is running");

var socket = require('socket.io');

var io = socket(server);

io.sockets.on('connection', newConnection);

function newConnection(socket) {
   console.log('new connection: ' + socket.id);

   socket.on('in', greetMsg);

   function greetMsg(data) {
       socket.broadcast.emit('in', data);
       console.log(data);
   }

   socket.on('other', boxSizer);

   function boxSizer(data) {
       socket.broadcast.emit('other', data);
       console.log(data);
   }

}
```

the relevant socket code in the client side looks like:

```
 socket = io.connect('http://<IP ADRESSS>:80');
 socket.on('in', otherGreeting);
 socket.on('other', function(data){
    otherBox.w = data.w;
    otherBox.h = data.h;
  });
```

It works perfectly on localhost:3000 on my machine but after having a lot of trouble setting up an accessible website I decided to bring it to amazon ec2 because I thought it would be easier.

Now I get this error:

```
Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 0.0.0.0:80
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1278:21)
    at listenInCluster (node:net:1343:12)
    at doListen (node:net:1480:7)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:81:21)
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:net:1322:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:80:21) {
  code: 'EACCES',
  errno: -13,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '0.0.0.0',
  port: 80
}
```

I read some stack overflow posts about limited permissions for low numbered ports but none of the solutions seemed to work on a an EC2 instance. I also cannot open any port to HTTP traffic except 80 in the EC2 security rules.

I feel like there is a simple fix here but I have looked through every StackOverflow post I could find and nothing has worked.